# maven test-jar: src/test/resources/file present but could not found by test

Tags: java, maven

I have module structure like

```
external_services/pom.xml
                 ifs/pom.xml
                     src/main/java
                     src/main/java/resources
                     src/test/java
                     src/test/java/resources/sample.json
inventory/pom.xml
         ifs/pom.xml
            src/main/java
            src/main/java/resources
            src/test/java/MyTest.java
```

In this `MyTest.java` I need to get `sample.json` since I want that to be shared across, so in `business/pom.xml` I add the following

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.org.my_services.external_services</groupId>
            <artifactId>ifs</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

so now when I run the test, I see

```
file:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/com/org/my_services/external_services/ifs/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ifs-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/sample.json (No such file or directory)
```

However, when I look at jar `ifs-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar`, I see it there

```
jar -tvf /Users/harith/.m2/repository/com/org/pryme_services/federated_services/ifs/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ifs-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
     0 Wed May 07 09:47:36 PDT 2014 META-INF/
   131 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/
     0 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/
     0 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/pryme_services/
     0 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/pryme_services/external_services/
     0 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/
     0 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/configuration/
   892 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/configuration/DevelopmentContextConfiguration.class
   888 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/configuration/ProductionContextConfiguration.class
  2381 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/IFSClientTest.class
  1422 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/InventoryRESTClientTest.class
  1033 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/MockIfsClient$1.class
  2350 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 com/org/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/MockIfsClient.class
142315 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 sample.json   // <-- here
     0 Wed May 07 09:47:36 PDT 2014 META-INF/maven/
     0 Wed May 07 09:47:36 PDT 2014 META-INF/maven/com.org.pryme_services.federated_services/
     0 Wed May 07 09:47:36 PDT 2014 META-INF/maven/com.org.pryme_services.federated_services/ifs/
  2391 Wed May 07 09:45:36 PDT 2014 META-INF/maven/com.org.pryme_services.federated_services/ifs/pom.xml
   138 Wed May 07 09:47:34 PDT 2014 META-INF/maven/com.org.pryme_services.federated_services/ifs/pom.properties
```

The way it is used in class is

```
inventoryPriceDetails = mapper.readValue(new File(getClass().getResource("/getInventoryAndPrice.json").getPath()), new TypeReference<List<InventoryPriceDetail>>() {
            });
```

I am not sure what I am missing, can some one please help?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things:

1)
external_services/pom.xml
                 ifs/pom.xml
                     src/main/java
                     src/main/java/resources
                     src/test/java
                     src/test/java/resources/sample.json

but maven expects
external_services/pom.xml
                 ifs/pom.xml
                     src/main/java
                     src/main/resources
                     src/test/java
                     src/test/resources/sample.json

"resource" parallel to "java". In your case "resource" is a package.

2) The file is called "sample.json" but you look for "getInventoryAndPrice.json"

3) new File does not work on a Path. You need getResourceAsStream() to extract data from a jar.
   (If you want to work with paths you need to work with the nio classes, not File)